# Vertically centering image in a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, getimagesize

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I've been trying to vertically center an image within a div, which I can do using CSS IF the height of the image is consistent. However (as always) things aren't as simple as that and the image height is different in pretty much every instance.

I'd like to be able to add a negative margin of half the image height, to the image, to pull it into the center of the div.

Any suggestions in how I do that?

This doesn't seem to be working :S

```
var $img = $('div#imageColumn img');
var h = $img.height();
$img.css('margin-top', + h / -2 + "px");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you show us your current code we might be able to help guide you better.

Comment: Do you really need to do this with jQuery? Check this out: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: Hi Tim - the images sizes are dynamic, so i need to use jquery to get the height and then apply the negative margin. I don't think CSS alone can do that?

Comment: @TimBüthe ~ nice read. I go back to [this](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/) myself from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

This code was found on SO some time ago. You use it like this

```
$(".yourclass").vAlign();
```

It calculates height of the parent element and centers it accordingly.

Function:

```
(function ($) {
    // VERTICALLY ALIGN FUNCTION
    $.fn.vAlign = function () {
        return this.each(function (i) {
            var ah = $(this).height();
            var ph = $(this).parent().height();
            var mh = Math.ceil((ph - ah) / 2);
            if (mh > 0) {
                $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
            } else {
                $(this).css('margin-top', 0);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo do not need jQuery for it, CSS could do it. Just set your image to be:

```
.yourDiv .yourImg{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* if you wonder for a maximum height just add */
  max-height: 200px;   
}
```

Also if you wonder for a hack to support inline-block on IE7 there you have:
http://www.kollerat.com/cms/index.php/Web-admin/HTML/IE7-and-inline-block.html

Comment: I need a soltion that works cross browser. Unfortunately that seems to only work in Firefox.

Comment: It works on FF, Chrome and IE8(or greater) if you want to support IE7 I pasted a link that explain you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks - but this still isn't working...

#imageColumn img {
 max-width: 445px;
 max-height: 333px;
 display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }

Comment: Check this: http://goo.gl/jl1gq I checked it on IE8, FF and Chrome and worked for me, Doctype at the beginning of the HTML is important for IE support (and also the hack of *display: inline;